# Upper bound for summation series (sliding window sampling)

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, summation, upper-lower-bounds

**Background:** Given a sequence of $n$ items, I am working on a sampling method where I slide a window of size $\ll n$ from start to end, and pick the *first item within each window with a certain probability*. Item $i$ is labeled with a weight number $x_i$ that indicates its relative importance, i.e., it will be picked with probability:

$$\frac{x_i}{\sum_{j=i}^{i+w} x_j}$$

I am trying to analyze the total expected size of my sample using this technique.

**Formulation:** Let $x_1, x_2, \ldots x_n$ be a sequence of numbers ($x_i \in \mathbb{N}$). What would be tight upper bound of the following summation:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-w} \frac{x_i}{\sum_{j=i}^{i+w} x_j}$$

Assume window length ($w+1$) is $\ll n$.
I am particularly interested in the case when $x_i \leq c, \forall i \in [1,n]$, where $c \ll n$ is a given constant.

Comment: With $~a:=\min\{x_1,...,x_n\}~$ , $~b:=\max\{x_1,...,x_n\}~$ we get $~\displaystyle \frac{(n-w)a}{(w+1)b}\leq\sum_{i=1}^{n-w} \frac{x_i}{\sum_{j=i}^{i+w} x_j}\leq\frac{(n-w)b}{(w+1)a}~$ .

Comment: Is there room for tighter bound? As an example, lets say the above sequence is $1, 100, 1, 100, 1, 100 \ldots$, and $n, w$ are any odd values.. then the sum is only $$\frac{n-w}{w+1}$$

Comment: If you have special values, then you can have special solutions, of course. If you have special whishes then add them to your question.

Comment: I want to highlight that the bound suggested by you is correct, but it is not tight for general case. (It is tight only for the special case of $a=b$)

Comment: It would be good if you describe the background of your question a bit, then maybe more people are interested to answer. --- You can get an approximation by using the arithmetic mean of each sum. But I don't know when you will get an upper or lower bound by this method.